# Faster to query in MYSQL or to use PHP logic

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a page that will pull many headlines from multiple categories based off a category id.

I'm wondering if it makes more sense to pull all the headlines and then sort them out via PHP if/ifelse statements or it is better to run multiple queries that each contain the headlines from each category.

Comment: What is the source of your category id's?  Do you have a categories table?  Are you getting ALL categories and headlines, or only selected categories?

Comment: I hadn't decided yet whether I was just going to have a category field per each headline row or to split it off as it's own table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not do it in one query? Something like:

```
SELECT headline FROM headlines WHERE category_id IN (1, 2, 3, ...);
```

If you filter your headlines in PHP, think how many you'll be throwing away. If you end up with removing just 10% of the headlines, it won't matter as much as when you'd be throwing away 90% of the results.

Comment: The most extreme example of this I've worked with was re-writing a multiple query with PHP processing block of code (written by a beginning coder) to use a single query that returned the desired results. Processing time reduced from over 20 seconds to nearly instantaneous.

Comment: Is each item provided by using IN an array of values?

Answer (score 2):

These kinds of questions are always hard to answer because the situation determines the best course. There is never a truly correct answer, only better ways. In my experience doesn't really matter whether you attempt to do the work in PHP or in the database because you should always try to cache the results of any expensive operation using a caching engine such as [memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php). That way you are not going to spend a lot of time in the db or in php itself since the results will be cached and ready instantaneously for use. When it comes down to it, unlss you profile your application using a tool like [xDebug](http://xdebug.org/), what you think are your performance bottlenecks are just guesses.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better not to overload the DB, because you might cause a bottleneck if you have many simultaneous queries.

However, handling your processing in PHP is *usually* better, as Apache will fork threads as it needs to handle multiple requests.

As usual, it all comes down to: "How much traffic is there?"

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can already do the selecting and ordering of the data for you. I suggest to be lazy and use this.

Also I'd look for a (1) query that fetches all the categories and their headlines at once. Would an ORDER BY category, publishdate or something do?

Answer (score 0):

Every trip to the database costs you something. Returning extra data that you then decide to ignore costs you something. So you're almost certainly better to let the database do your pruning.

I'm sure one could come up with some case where deciding what data you need makes the query hugely complex and thus difficult for the database to optimize, while you could do it in your code easily. But if we're talking about "select headline from story where category='Sports'" followed by "select headline from story where category='Politics'" then "select headline from story where category='Health'" etc, versus "select category, headline from story where category in ('Health','Sports','Politics')", the latter is clearly better.

Answer (score 0):

On the topic of "Faster to query in MYSQL or to use PHP logic", which is how I ended up on this question 10 years later.   I have determined that the correct answer is "it depends".  There are just too many examples where using the DB saves processing time over writing PHP Code.... but there are just as many examples where writing PHP Code saves time on excessively complex MySQL queries.

There is no right answer here.   If you end up here, like I did, then the best I can suggest is try to solve your problem with the skills that you have.  Start first with the Query and try to solve it, if you run into issues then start thinking about just gathering the data and running the logic through PHP code to come up with a solution.

At the end of the day, you need to solve a problem....   if you solve it, but its not fast enough, then thats another problem... work on optimizing which may end up meaning that you go back to writing more MySQL logic.

Use the 80/20 rule and try to get things 80% of the way there as quickly as possible.  You can go back and optimize once its workable.  Spending all your effort on making it perfect the first time will surely mean you miss your deadline.

Thats my $0.02